# How to add header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:" to certain response codes

Tags: nginx

So i am getting the nice `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` when my NGINX returns a `413 Request Entity Too Large`. This is causing issues with my frontend app as i can not read the response. Is it possible to add in the header for only certain errors such as the above mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

From the `Nginx` doc for [add_header](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) , you can add headers for certain response codes such as **200, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, 307 or 308**, but not for **413**

And if your Nginx version is  **Nginx 1.7.5** or later, Try using the following syntax

```
add_header name value always;
```

Since the `always` parameter specifies that, the header field will be added regardless of the response code.

Comment: so i can only do always? and not specific ones?

Comment: yup, in your case.